# Name of Property: The Order Of Parameters in a Function Does Not Matter

Tags: terminology

As the title says: I have a function where the order of parameters does not matter. An example would be `ADD`: `ADD(1,2)` and `ADD(2,1)` can be used interchangeably, the order of parameters does not matter. `DIVIDE` does not carry this property.

What is the property's name?

Comment: This is called [commutativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property).

Comment: Commutation, commuting operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mathematics, it is called "symmetry".  See [Function of several real variables - Symmetry (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_of_several_real_variables#Symmetry)

For an operation, rather than a function, "commutative" would be more usual.  (Thanks Noah)

If you are thinking of computing languages, which your syntax suggests, then a different term might be preferred but this is not the place to ask about that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [commutative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property).